QGIS Form: The SUM field is not populated as expected
I created a form in QGIS to collate the data from a created points layer. In this layer, I am trying to sum the values from Field_A grouped by Field_B and Field_C. I used the following expression:
sum("Field_A", group_by:= concat("Field_B", "Field_C"))
Field_A was added as checkbox to the form which the stored values were set as 1 and 0.  My issue is the sum values had not been automatically populated in the 'Total' field as expected. Everytime, I add a point, I had to save and close the layer and then open and edit the form by re-ticking the checkbox and save the layer so I can see the right sum in the 'Total' field.
In this post: QGIS: configure Attributes Form for calculations 'Oisin' said that there is a function called current_value() which could help but I don't know how to edit the above script to make it works.
